# How can I make this JavaScript code shorter

Tags: javascript

I have a code that will make pictures disappear and show and vice-versa. My problem is how can I make this shorter? I have multiple element id's with only same purpose to 'be removed' and showed up again after clicking the button. I called each of the id. Is there anyway I could make this shorter?
Here is the code

```
const liteSwitch = document.getElementById('lite-mode-switch');
liteSwitch.addEventListener('click',myFunction);


function myFunction() {


    var b = document.getElementById("background"); 
    var c = document.getElementById("backgrounds");
    var x = document.getElementById("remove");
    var y = document.getElementById("remove1");
    var z = document.getElementById("remove2");
    var a = document.getElementById("remove3");

    if (x.style.display === "none") 
    {
        x.style.display = "block";
    }
    if (y.style.display === "none") 
    {
        y.style.display = "block";
    } 
    if (z.style.display === "none") 
    {
        z.style.display = "block";
    } 
    if (a.style.display === "none") 
    {
        a.style.display = "block";
    }
    if (b.style.display === "none") 
    {
        b.style.display = "block";
    }
    if (c.style.display === "none") 
    {
        c.style.display = "block";
    }  
   else 
    {
      x.style.display = "none";
      y.style.display = "none";
      z.style.display = "none";
      a.style.display = "none";
      b.style.display = "none";
      c.style.display = "none";
     }


   }
```

Comment: create a function to do the `if ... === none ... block` stuff

Comment: It would be easy to understand if you could add your `HTML` content also

Comment: @SAM - why? makes no difference

Comment: @JaromandaX It well could IMO, depends on the situation

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate the id strings, and use ternary operator:

```
function myFunction() {
    for (let id of ["background", "backgrounds", "remove", "remove1", "remove2", "remove3", "remove4"]) {
        let style = document.querySelector(id).style;
        style.display = style.display === "none" ? "" : "none"; 
    }
}
```

I should note however that the use of `id` attributes with a sequential number in it (like `remove1`, `remove2`...) is a code smell: most often this can be better done with a `class` attribute that these elements would share. Then iteration is possible using `querySelectorAll`. This leads to better code.

Also toggling the `display` style can be better done with toggling a class for that purpose.

For instance, define this class in your CSS:

```css
.hidden { display: none }
```

And provide another class to *all* elements that should be toggled. For instance:

```html
<img src="remove.jpg" class="toggleme">
<img src="remove1.jpg" class="toggleme">
<img src="remove2.jpg" class="toggleme">
```

Then your function could be:

```
function myFunction() {
    for (let elem of document.querySelectorAll(".toggleme")) {
        elem.classList.toggle("hidden");
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much!! the last one work! thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const liteSwitch = document.getElementById("lite-mode-switch");
const ids = [
  "remove3",
  "background",
  "backgrounds",
  "remove",
  "remove1",
  "remove2",
];

function myFunction() {
  ids.forEach((el) =>
    document.querySelector(`#${el}`).classList.toggle("hide")
  );
}

liteSwitch.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

```css
.show {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="lite-mode-switch">lite mode switch</button>
<img class="show" src="https://picsum.photos/200" id="background">
<img class="show" src="https://picsum.photos/200" id="backgrounds">
<img class="show" src="https://picsum.photos/200" id="remove">
<img class="show" src="https://picsum.photos/200" id="remove1">
<img class="show" src="https://picsum.photos/200" id="remove2">
<img class="show" src="https://picsum.photos/200" id="remove3">
```

Comment: thank you!!  I'm gonna try this one too. thank you very much